# 2d space indexing that supports efficient adding and removing static circular regions

Tags: algorithm, indexing, geometry, quadtree

I need to quickly set all pixels in a circle (x0,y0,r) to solid or empty on a big, per-pixel map. Like in worms or liero game when you blow up terrain with a bomb.

I considered quad tree and simple 2d array, but quad tree seems bad for adding/removing circles, and simple 2d array takes up a lot of memory for big maps

Is there some better algorithm that could make this fast and small?

Comment: What are you going to do with these data?

Comment: Draw terrain (background texture for empty pixels, foreground texture for solid pixels), and do collision detection for 2 players and their bullets with these pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a quadkey. Translate the points to a binary and interleave it. Treat it as base 4 number. It used in bing maps for the tiles of the map.